# Jquery Image size manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a jQuery image viewing gallery so you hover over the image and it becomes the background the gal (gallery) div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img1").hover(function(){
        var img1 = document.getElementById("gal");
        gal.style.background="url(images/img1.png), black";
    });
    $("#img1").mouseout(function(){
        gal.style.background="none";
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img2").hover(function(){
        var img2 = document.getElementById("gal");
        gal.style.background="url(images/img2.png), black";
    });
    $( "#img2" ).mouseout(function(){
         gal.style.background="none";
    });
});
```

The html code

```
        <section>       
 <h1> Images</h1>
 <h3> Photos </h3>
 <div id="gal">
 </div>
 <img id="img" src="images/img1.png" width="100px" height="100px"/>
 <img id="img" src="images/img2.png" width="100px" height="100px"/>

    </section>
```

This is my code and it works perfectly fine but using this code I am required to input each div individually.

Is there a way so when you hover over an image it knows what image that is and it makes the div background equal that? Thank you for your help.

P.S. I am quite new to JavaScript.

Comment: Could you post the HTML for the gallery as well? It will help when writing code for the selectors. Essentially you create a generic *hover* function and use the `this` keyword to manipulate the image in question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var gal = $("#gal"); //Avoid repeated traverse

   $("img").hover(function(){
     gal.css("background",'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')');  
     //Assuming you want to set current image as background image
    });

   $( "img" ).mouseout(function(){
      gal.css("background","none");  
   });
  });
```

This is basic mechanism. You may have to change selector and path as per your requirement.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NNGdR/5/

Comment: Thanks alot but this does not seem to work I changed it slightly to fit the code but no luck? Is there possibly another way?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? I can see that you are using same ID for two different image. Better use class instead.

Comment: Html:  <section>  
<h1> Images</h1>
<h3> Photos </h3>
<div id="gal">
</div>
<img class="img-class" src="images/scambox.png" width="100px" height="100px"/>
<img class="img-class" src="images/scambox.png" width="100px" height="100px"/>

  </section>
css:
#gal {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
margin: auto;

}
I am simply unable to get it to work I'm not sure what I am doing wrong though thank you

Comment: Have you given height, width to div#gal ?

Comment: I have added a hight
I mean this $(document).ready(function(){ $("#img1").hover(function(){ var img1 = document.getElementById("gal"); gal.style.background="url(images/img1.png), black"; }); $("#img1").mouseout(function(){ gal.style.background="none"; }); }); Worked perfectly but it is simply impractical with the amount of photos I am planning so i'm stuck

Comment: I have edited the answer and it's working. Check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NNGdR/5/

Comment: Thank you so much I wont have time to check it now but I'm sure it works I would vote you up if I could ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the same class to each img. Example :

```
<img class="img-class" src="img1" />
<img class="img-class" src="img2" />
<img class="img-class" src="img3" />
<img class="img-class" src="img4" />

$(document).ready(function(){
       var gal = $("#gal"); //Avoid repeated traverse
      //Assign class so that this doesnt happen on other images in the html
       $(".img-class").hover(function(){
         gal.css("background",$(this).attr('src'));  
         //set current image as background
        });

       $( ".img-class" ).mouseout(function(){
          gal.css("background","none");  
       });
    });
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks alot, but neither of these seem to work I have adjusted my code accordingly for each but no luck. Is there something I could be doing wrong or another way?

Comment: I mean this 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img1").hover(function(){
        var img1 = document.getElementById("gal");
        gal.style.background="url(images/img1.png), black";
    });
    $("#img1").mouseout(function(){
        gal.style.background="none";
    });
});
Worked perfectly but it is simply impractical with the amount of photos I am planning so i'm stuck

Comment: Sorry didnt mean to repeat the answer.Just being more specific with regards to class etc.